# Rails internationalisation for web form validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization, rails-i18n

I am developing an application that would employ a server-side phone number validation for the various countries it is deployed in. As an example, the UK mobile numbers all contain 11 digits starting with 07. In another country the mobile numbers may contain a different number of digits or may start with a different code. I would like to use such country-specific phone number specification to validate the input of a web form. Please, note that the application will be deployed separately for each country. So for the UK version of the application a number starting with 099 or containing just 10 digits shall raise a submission error (e.g. "Invalid mobile phone number") whereas, say, the German version of the application shall not raise an error at all.

What is the most elegant way to implement such locale-specific form validation? I had a look at the i18n gem but I am not sure it would easily support it.

Answer (score 1):

If your validation is server side, may be you can take a look at [joost/phony_rails](https://github.com/joost/phony_rails)

I quote the description :
This Gem adds useful methods to your Rails app to validate, display and save phone numbers. It uses the super awesome Phony gem

Comment: Thanks - it is nice to know about this gem. Yes, my validation is server-side. But I would like to define the validation conditions myself. The question is how to switch between validating conditions depending on the locale? So it is, actually, a broader question that goes beyond international phone formats.

Comment: To validate, you can do something like this ````validate :your_fct```` (note 'validate' without 's'). In the function ````your_fct```` you can do ````case/when```` to test the locale and use the appropriate validation condition. It's not easy in a comment to give more explanations but I can write an answer if you want.